# Why does MeGUI have a warning icon?

Tags: megui

What does it mean when MeGUI's taskbar icon has a warning over it?

I've let the updater make everything current, but I've still got that icon.

As far as I can tell I'm able to use it as normal.

[image: MeGUI warning icon]

Comment: What happens if you run it as admin?

Comment: @Karan It still has the warning sign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MeGUI has a Logs tab. In there I was able to see that it was complaining about Haali Matroska Splitter not being installed.

I guess this is a new warning that came with the latest update.